# MongoDB: sorting output from shell is different from pymongo's

Tags: mongodb

When executing the following query from Mongo shell I get the wanted results, i.e. output first sorted by category and then by count in descending order within the category.

```
db.getCollection('DynamicData').aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$calls" },
    { "$group": { "_id": {"category": "$calls.category","api": "$calls.api"},"count": { "$sum": 1} } },
    {  "$sort": { "_id.category": 1, "count": -1}}
], {allowDiskUse: true})
```

However, when I try to execute the same query via PyMongo I get a different result, i.e. output sorted just by count and not by category. How is this possible? Here below is the python code:

```
pipeline = [
    { "$unwind" : "$calls" },
    { "$group": { "_id": {"category": "$calls.category","api": "$calls.api"},"count": { "$sum": 1} } },
    {  "$sort": { "_id.category": 1, "count": -1}}
]

output = list(db.DynamicData.aggregate(pipeline,allowDiskUse=True))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of Python's dictionaries nature. Look at the docs [here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html). As the documentation states:

> As python dictionaries don’t maintain order you should use SON or collections.OrderedDict where explicit ordering is required eg “$sort”:

So you should rewrite your code to someting like this:

```
pipeline = [
    { "$unwind" : "$calls" },
    { "$group": { "_id": {"category": "$calls.category","api": "$calls.api"},"count": { "$sum": 1} } },
    {  "$sort": SON([("_id.category", 1), ("count", -1)]) }
]
```